# Boot to Login Screen Raspberry

Tags: security

Currently the raspbian os we installed is not booting up with a login screen. 
How can I boot it up to a login screen so that we can enter a username & password and so that it doesn't go directly to desktop?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

you can open a terminal and type

```
sudo raspi-config
```

There you can go to

```
3 Enable Boot to Desktop/Scratch
```

and select Console.

After a reboot, you should be good to go.

Answer (score 1):

Open the terminal and type:
`sudo raspi-config`

Then select Boot > Desktop / CLI > *Desktop* instead of *Desktop autologin*.

Now just reboot.

Answer (score 0):

If you select boot to desktop, it will not give you a login screen. The only time you have have to put in a password is if you select boot to terminal.

I don't believe there is a way for you to have a login screen.

Comment: This is incorrect; you may have to disable *autologin*, (which is a separate issue from whether you boot to console or desktop, although I think it requires desktop mode), but there is a GUI login screen.