# Disable automatic locking of screen (and all other interruptions)

Tags: raspbian, screen-saver

I installed `xscreensaver` to avoid screen sleep and other interruptions, because I'm showing a `feh` picture presentation on a HDMI connected TV 24/7.

I managed to disable screesavers and screen blanking/sleeping/powering off but I'm getting stuck with a login screen, which appears after a few hours. The `feh` presentation is not visible anymore then, just the desktop background:

[image: Lock Screen after couple of hours]

I disabled screen locking in `xscreensaver` as well, as you can see in the [configuration file](https://gist.github.com/nihebe/3d7322d19d189e2e406370156c703371).
For debugging purposes I also activated `xscreensavers` logging in verbose mode and attached the regarding logs in the same Gist as linked above. I think it starts properly.

Are there any other components in Raspbian GNU/Linux 9, which could activate the lockscreen?

Any help is appreciated!

Comment: I updated the xscreensaver logfile (https://gist.github.com/nihebe/3d7322d19d189e2e406370156c703371) - it tries to blank the screen every 10 minutes, however I never noticed any blanking.

Comment: that does not appear to be screen saver related .... it looks like an auto logout process ..... you are asking your question in the wrong place .... it is a Linux question, not an RPi question

Comment: here is a discussion about a similar problem ... https://groups.google.com/forum/m/#!topic/linux.debian.user/X39IumadTfo

Answer (score 1):

I finally found the answer here: [Boot to Login Screen Raspberry](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/15552/boot-to-login-screen-raspberry)

you can open a terminal and type

```
sudo raspi-config
```

There you can go to

```
3-->Boot Options
```

Then

```
B1-->Desktop / CLI
```

And there you can choose:

```
B4-->Desktop Autologin Desktop GUI, automatically logged in as 'pi' user
```

After a reboot, you should access directly the desktop.

Comment: But does this prevent locking the user session when you're already logged in?